# Trying to make JavaScript trigger a PHP script to add a row to a table, but it's not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this in my JavaScript file. I know it gets called:

```
        var data = "hi";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../register_email.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                alert("worked!");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("NOPE");
                $(".contact-form").hide();
                $(".alt-contact").hide();

                // Inserts divs making up the success message for the form submission
                $(".contact-form").html("<div class='error-message'><div class='error-image'></div><div class='error-title'>Whoops! An error occurred.</div><div class='error-body'>That's strange... Please <a href='mailto:support@syllableapp.com'>email me</a> instead. Sorry about that.</div></div>");

                $(".contact-form").fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
```

And it calls this PHP file:

```
<?php
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "name", "pass", "db");

    if ($db->connect_error) {
        echo "Could not connect to database.";
        exit;
    }
    else {
        $db->query("INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('trying')");
        echo 1;
    }
?>
```

But it never does anything. It just alerts "NOPE" back at me. I just want it to add the row, but when I check my server it never does that. But if I just navigate to register_emails.php in my browser it loads and adds it.

Comment: is there any error in the browser console

Comment: did you check whether the script is executing by putting an alert statement

Comment: Are you getting rows inserted into your table?

Comment: What's in `errorThrown`?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `data` is not properly formatted. It should either be an object, or a string in the form `param=val&param=val&...`.

Comment: Can you try with an absolute URL (something starting with `/`).

Comment: are you using the right file name. your code says register_email.php but then your comments say register_emails.php. are you missing the s?

Comment: I get these errors: http://i.imgur.com/qo3FW5z.png and http://i.imgur.com/xk9bz0F.png >_<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably, the error happens due to a wrong URL, use an absolute URL (if possible) and make sure the page is accessible.

Also, add these lines in your `.error(/*...*/)` function so you know what errors are happening:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Error Message: ' + textStatus);
    alert('HTTP Error: ' + errorThrown);
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I get these errors: http://i.imgur.com/qo3FW5z.png and http://i.imgur.com/xk9bz0F.png >_<

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not valid JSON, you can do something like this:

`{ "message": "hi" }`

[JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/)